# Obtaining the number of inputs from a user in java

Tags: java

I'm new to Java. I hope this question sounds sane enough.
Say, for example the user  has to input 3 numbers per line till he inputs 0 0 0 (which I managed  with a do while loop).
Now, I want  to know the total number of inputs the user entered till 0 0 0. How do I obtain that using java?
Here's a bit of my code:

```
 int a,b, c;
do{ a= input.nextInt();
    b= input.nextInt();
    c= input.nextInt();
    }
    while( a !=0 && b !=0 && c !=0);
```

Comment: keep a count and increment it each time the loop executes?

Comment: How does that help me get the no of inputs?

Comment: count * 3 is the total number of numbers input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 int a,b, c;
int  count=0;
do{ a= input.nextInt();
    b= input.nextInt();
    c= input.nextInt();
     count++;
    }
    while( a !=0 && b !=0 && c !=0);
```

the total will be count

Answer (score 0):

Just count them, like

```
    int count;
     int a,b, c;
    do{ a= input.nextInt();
        b= input.nextInt();
        c= input.nextInt();
        }
      count + = 1;
    while( a !=0 && b !=0 && c !=0);
```